# MySQL said: #1194 - Table 'tablename' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

If tables are crashing it means something is wrong with my system.

```
MySQL said: 

#1194 - Table 'tablename' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

My website is currently down because of this.

I know how to repair table from phpmyadmin but is it safe way to repair?

What is the important factor for this issue?

Question. Generally, Why table get crashed?

Answers. These may be the reasons -

1. Server's disk space was full. (Please check disk space in live server)
2. Incorrect shutdown MySQL server/Improperly closing the tables while using the databases.
3. More server load.

Comment: can you post the query ?

Comment: this may helpful http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/13/10-ways-to-crash-or-overload-mysql/

Comment: "*Generally, Why table get crashed?*" because it's MyISAM... It has a reputation for not being safe.

Comment: What's your current system uptime? Could be improper system shutdown. Check logs, both /var/log/messages and mysqld.log, it could be OOM killer or mysqld process failure.

Comment: what happens if disk space is full?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First of all - there are many reasons for a crashed table.

- harddisk failure
- sudden server reboot
- server crash
- firmware problems (raid controller or bios)
- defects in the cabling
- etc.

A repair with phpmyadmin does basically the same as the mysqlrepair commandline. I would suggest to repair everything on command line:

```
mysqlrepair -A --auto-repair
mysqlrepair -A -o
```

Or start a test:

```
mysqlrepair -A -c
```

Comment: It says mysqlrepair is not installed. Is this the same as run mysqlcheck -uUSER -pPASSWORD  --repair --extended -A

Answer (score 27):

If you don't have commandline tools needed, and reason for crash is most likely is MYSQL itself, run this from MYSQL to repair a table:

```
REPAIR TABLE db_name.table_name;
```

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --check --all-databases
(Password prompted)
```

Enter MySQL password for user root and everything is done.

Answer (score 7):

**Solution :**

Just go to database and **select table** which has problem and **select "repair table" option** it will fix crash entries in table and solve your problem

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can repair table from phpmyadmin, it will not affect your data and you can also repair table from shell with 'myisamchk' command.

Answer (score 1):

I use this from the command line:

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --check --optimize --all-databases
```

Comment: It gives: "Error:  mysqlcheck doesn't support multiple contradicting commands."

Comment: Right i also got the same error. Remove --optimize then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ssh access to server you can log in and then execute:

```
df -h
```

and you could see something like this:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/cciss/xxxx      19G  825M   18G   5% /
/dev/cciss/xxxx     9.4G  4.8G  4.2G  54% /usr
/dev/cciss/xxxx      15G  1.8G   12G  13% /var
/dev/cciss/xxxx      19G   18G    0G   0% /opt
/dev/cciss/xxxx     4.7G  243M  4.3G   6% /tmp
/dev/cciss/xxxx     9.4G  1.5G  7.5G  17% /home
```

It's LAMP installed on `/opt`, after having some free disk space, you can run the query (as above was wrote):

```
Repair table db.mytablecrashed
```

And you get in the last row:

```
Table               OP        Msg_type  Msg_text
...
db.mytablecrashed   repair    status    OK
```